# How to copy the contents of the tag?

Tags: javascript, html

How to copy the contents of a "div" tag with a unique id "text_block"

```
<div class="other"><div id="text_block">html text</div></div>
```

and add to MYSQL using php?

Comment: `innerHTML` is what you are talking about?

Comment: use AJAX, either in vanilla JavaScript or a framework like jQuery.

Comment: Without the use of a client side scripting language, you will need to implement an HTML form with a `<textarea>` element in it that will allow a block of text to be submitted to the server.

Comment: @DhavalMarthak the tags aren't there but there's no way to do this 100% server side without a `GET` or `POST` request either by clicking a link or submitting a form. __edit__ well, the edit now contains the `javascript` tag :)

Comment: @martincarlin87 I know that but just to remind `OP` to tag question properly to get desired answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use InnerHTML to copy the contents of the tag

**main.php:**

```
<?php
    @mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    @mysql_select_db("DataBaseName");
    if(isset($_GET["innethtml"]))
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `TableName` (`name`) VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["innethtml"]) . "')")
?>
```

**index.html:**

```
<html>
        ...
        <script type="text/javascript">
              function send(){
                  var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
                  x.open("GET", "main.php?innethtml=" + document.getElementsByID("text_block").innerHTML, true);
                  x.send(null);
              }
        </script>
        </body>
            ...
            <div class="other"/><div id="text_block"/>html text</div></div>
            ...
            <input type="button" value="Send" onclick="send()"/>
        </body>
</html>
```